# Nginx php5-fpm varnish taking high CPU. Load average is over 32

Tags: nginx, mysql, php, wordpress, varnish

I'm on a server with the following config:

32 GB RAM
12 core processor

and it's running single wordpress on nginx, varnish, php5-fpm, fastcgi.
Everything was running fine, but suddenly after yesterday night the whole site is extremely slow and unresponsive. Upon inspection, I found that mysql was using a lot of CPU. After a lot of research online, I disabled XML-RPC and mysql CPU load came down drastically.

But the problem still persists, my CPU was almost 100%. I see that php5-fpm processes are taking up all the CPU.

Here's the result of top

```
top - 10:30:33 up  7:10,  1 user,  load average: 31.35, 31.87, 31.85
Tasks: 238 total,  27 running, 179 sleeping,  32 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 84.9 us, 11.7 sy,  0.0 ni,  3.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  32948544 total, 11695168 used, 21253376 free,   408404 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.  3151748 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
12179 mysql     20   0 6233684 998836   7632 S 109.2  3.0 371:56.58 mysqld
18533 nginx     20   0 1007708 769740  26008 R  57.5  2.3   3:33.24 php5-fpm
18487 nginx     20   0  600672 361312  26212 R  51.7  1.1   4:13.51 php5-fpm
18657 nginx     20   0  280024  42640  25436 R  51.7  0.1   0:46.94 php5-fpm
18459 nginx     20   0  996592 753804  25764 R  40.2  2.3   4:53.79 php5-fpm
18469 nginx     20   0 1010296 768676  25704 R  40.2  2.3   4:22.98 php5-fpm
18545 nginx     20   0  277216  40060  25740 R  40.2  0.1   2:53.74 php5-fpm
18547 nginx     20   0  684952 441796  25616 R  40.2  1.3   2:58.57 php5-fpm
18629 nginx     20   0  280452  42752  25444 R  40.2  0.1   1:22.99 php5-fpm
18460 nginx     20   0  282796  45920  25828 R  34.5  0.1   5:22.28 php5-fpm
18461 nginx     20   0  276952  40200  25636 R  34.5  0.1   4:13.64 php5-fpm
18462 nginx     20   0  278752  41504  25672 R  34.5  0.1   4:16.16 php5-fpm
18540 nginx     20   0  277744  41096  25740 R  34.5  0.1   3:02.92 php5-fpm
18624 nginx     20   0  278648  41060  25588 R  34.5  0.1   1:27.54 php5-fpm
18452 nginx     20   0  278752  41696  25732 S  28.7  0.1   4:25.82 php5-fpm
18458 nginx     20   0  282488  45512  25684 S  28.7  0.1   4:44.26 php5-fpm
18472 nginx     20   0  282652  45976  25948 R  28.7  0.1   4:34.61 php5-fpm
18486 nginx     20   0 1007732 769472  25800 R  28.7  2.3   4:03.61 php5-fpm
18491 nginx     20   0  282488  45584  25764 R  28.7  0.1   4:06.75 php5-fpm
18495 nginx     20   0  280744  43216  25744 R  28.7  0.1   3:37.82 php5-fpm
18496 nginx     20   0  282488  44924  25908 R  28.7  0.1   3:38.28 php5-fpm
18562 nginx     20   0  282488  45412  25584 R  28.7  0.1   2:53.19 php5-fpm
18575 nginx     20   0  282760  46068  26192 R  28.7  0.1   2:34.81 php5-fpm
18455 nginx     20   0  278904  41532  25716 S  23.0  0.1   4:22.13 php5-fpm
18468 nginx     20   0  278776  42120  25732 R  23.0  0.1   4:09.41 php5-fpm
18490 nginx     20   0  280840  44148  26172 R  23.0  0.1   3:39.08 php5-fpm
18492 nginx     20   0  282232  45260  25652 R  23.0  0.1   4:07.21 php5-fpm
18514 nginx     20   0  282608  45716  25732 R  23.0  0.1   3:44.15 php5-fpm
18576 nginx     20   0  279416  41964  25496 R  23.0  0.1   2:09.75 php5-fpm
18656 nginx     20   0  279560  42428  25508 S  23.0  0.1   0:49.84 php5-fpm
18465 nginx     20   0  284492  47860  26252 R  17.2  0.1   5:09.60 php5-fpm
10165 nobody    20   0 11.233g 2.437g  83232 S  11.5  7.8  23:56.78 varnishd
18686 root      20   0   24948   1656   1080 R  11.5  0.0   0:00.04 top
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   5.7  0.0   2:48.56 rcuos/0
18122 nginx     20   0   36700   7428   1040 S   5.7  0.0   1:04.16 nginx
18129 nginx     20   0   33836   4568   1040 S   5.7  0.0   0:25.52 nginx
```

As you can see Load Average is a whopping `31.35, 31.87, 31.85`
What can cause such high CPU usage. I've tried tweaking everything from mysql to nginx to varnish, but nothing seems to be working. I've tried playing around with `pm` value in my `php5 conf` file too, but here I'm, tearing my hair apart.

Please help.

The website gets a lot of traffic, say 2000 to 3000 concurrent users on an average. :(

UPDATE:

Including the nginx conf files:
**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  12;
worker_rlimit_nofile 20000;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  3000;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}


http {
    server_names_hash_bucket_size  64;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:100m rate=3r/m;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    client_header_timeout 180;
    client_body_timeout 180;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
    client_body_buffer_size 10M;
    client_max_body_size 32m;
    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    port_in_redirect off;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name mysite.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.mysite.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    ## Your website name goes here.
    server_name www.mysite.com;
    ## Your only path reference.
    root /var/www/;
    listen 8080;
    ## This should be in your http block and if it is, it's not needed here.
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    include conf.d/drop;

        location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
             try_files $uri =404;
             # proxy buffers - no 502 errors!
             proxy_buffer_size               128k;
             proxy_buffers                   4 256k;
             proxy_busy_buffers_size         256k;

            fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-fpm-www.sock;
            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

             location ~* wp\-login\.php {
                limit_req   zone=one  burst=1 nodelay;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-fpm-www.sock;
              }

        }
        location /xmlrpc.php {
          deny all;
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your nginx configuration for us? Specifically your fpm settings.

Comment: @NathanC I've added the nginx config. Kindly help.

Comment: Hmm, a similar question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732436/php5-fpm-randomly-starts-consuming-a-lot-of-cpu ...try playing with the php-fpm configuration. Those child processes are running for a long time so `pm.max_requests` could be lowered so they recycle more.

Comment: **running single wordpress**, but in that WordPress can many slow (read: bad) queries? Can you install Query Monitor plugin and check how many bad queries.

Comment: You are actually not having the cached content from the perspective of WordPress, right? Not using caching plugins.

Comment: Let me try query monitor. Also I'm using W3TC

Comment: This could simply be a busy server and a plugin/theme that takes a lot of CPU. Do you have Varnish caching pages for users that aren't logged in? If not have you tried Nginx page caching? I have Nginx page caching tutorial here https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/

Comment: Also try adding the plugin "Disable JSON API".

Comment: The fact that you're running php-fpm under ```nginx``` user is very alarming and plain wrong.

Answer (score 1):

From another point of view I noticed something. If you don't use Memcache you don't need Varnish. Varnish is "pasato", since not planning to support **spdy** for a long time as Varnish author said once.

Also I see that your caching layer is actually on application layer. The W3TC plugin you are using.

Still you may add to your configuration. I haven't saw that.

```
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 365d;
}
```

Also improve what you allow on your web server.

```
## Only allow these request methods ##
     if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) {
         return 444;
     }
## Do not accept DELETE, SEARCH and other methods ##
```